# Validar Login y Register Sql Server

Tags: sql-server

Hola amigos quiero validar un Login y un Register, Donde el login ovbiamente si un correo en la base de datos salga un mensaje diciendo Bienvenido y si no un mensaje donde salga Usuario no encontrado, y en el registro donde si un email ya en la base de datos no se pueda registrar
Aca mi tabla

```
create table tb_usuarios(
idusuario int primary key identity(1,1),
nombre varchar(300) not null,
email varchar(200) not null unique,
contrasena varchar(200) not null,
imagen varchar(200),
rol varchar(200) not null,
google bit
)
```

Registro:

```
create proc usp_registrar_Usuarios
@nombre varchar(300),
@email varchar(200) ,
@contrasena varchar(200),
@imagen varchar(200),
@rol varchar(200),
@google bit
as
begin
insert into tb_usuarios(nombre,email,contrasena,imagen,rol,google) values(@nombre,@email,@contrasena,@imagen,@rol,@google)
end
```

Login:

```
create proc usp_listar_usuariosemail
@email varchar(200)
as
begin
select * from tb_usuarios
where email=@email
end
```

Comment: No se entiende bien que queres. Queres hacer todo eso adentro del sqlserver? como recibis los datos? donde queres mostrar los carteles???

Comment: Puedes probar con la función [EXISTS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql)  en conjunto con IF.